# I cannot integrate with mysqldump.exe on java

Tags: java, backup, mysql

Am trying to backup MySQL database via mysqldump utility attached with MySQL. My code is on JAVA.But it returns nothing so i cannot backup the database. Here is the function used to do that :

```
public String getServerDumpData()
{
    new Database("Database.ini");
    StringBuilder dumpdata = new StringBuilder();
    String execline = "";
    try {
        if(Database.ConnectToDatabase()){
            // Set path. Set location of mysqldump
            //  For example: current user folder and lib subfolder
            if( HelpersToolbox.IsWindows() ){
                execline = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\mysql\\mysqldump.exe";
            }else{
                execline = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\lib\\mysqldump.exe";
            }
            // Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
            // OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
            // OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
            String command[] = new String[]{ execline,
                            "--host=" + Database.DbServer,
                            "--port=" + Database.DbPort,
                            "--user=" + Database.DbUsername,
                            "--password=" + Database.DbPassword,
                            "--compact",
                            "--complete-insert",
                            "--extended-insert",
                            "--skip-comments",
                            "--skip-triggers",
                            Database.DbName };

            // Run mysqldump
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            Process process = pb.start();



            InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));


            int count;
            char[] cbuf = new char[STREAM_BUFFER];

            // Read datastream
            while ((count = br.read(cbuf, 0, STREAM_BUFFER)) != -1){
                dumpdata.append(cbuf, 0, count);

            }
            // Close
            br.close();
            in.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
    return dumpdata.toString();
}
```

It cannot access the loop at the end . So what's the problem here ?

Comment: `It cannot access the loop at the end ` ??

Comment: It cannot access the loop at all.

Comment: If you check the exitValue of the *Process*, what do you get? Also, have you tried printing the command array to see that it actually holds what you think it should?

Comment: when i try to print exitValue i get this exception :java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited

Answer (score 0):

You have the data on the error stream which you either also have to read or merge with the output stream by using

```
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
```

before starting the process.

Comment: @Hatem But did it give you an indication on what is wrong (if you print the data as you receive it)?

Comment: dumpdata.toString() returned as empty string. It must be not empty at the normal conditions.